# Parsing yaml list and dicts in Python

Tags: python, pyyaml

Using Python3 and pyyaml how can I accomplish the following?

Yaml:

```
role-templates:
- readonly:
  - step1;
  - step2;
- readwrite:
  - step1;
  - step2
  - step3;
```

Given a role (readonly or readwrite), I need a list of steps.

This doesn't work because I have a list and not a dict.

```
with open('dbconfig.yaml') as f:
    baseConfig = yaml.safe_load(f)

roleType = 'readonly'
roleSteps = baseConfig['role-templates'][roleType]
```

The above code fails to index into role-templates.

Alternatively, I was starting to head down this route:

```
roleType = 'readonly'
roleSteps =  first_true(roleTemplates, None, lambda x: x == roleType)
```

How can I extract the steps for a given role?

Comment: You should look at the structure that represents - `role-templates` is an array of objects. If you're stuck with that YAML, I'd suggest you turn that list into a dict first, but it would be better to start with the right structure from the beginning.

Comment: So change the yaml to get the parser to create the objects I need?

Comment: If you _can_ change it, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no way to change the YAML file, and have to deal with this after loading:

```py
d = yaml.safe_load(io.StringIO("""role-templates:
- readonly:
  - step1;
  - step2;
- readwrite:
  - step1;
  - step2
  - step3;
"""))

d['role-templates'] = {k: v for d in d['role-templates'] for k, v in d.items()}
```

If you are the only user of that YAML definition, then change it:

```py
d = yaml.safe_load(io.StringIO("""role-templates:
 readonly:
  - step1;
  - step2;
 readwrite:
  - step1;
  - step2
  - step3;
"""))
```

In either case, the resulting content of `d['role-templates']` is a proper `dict`, and you can get e.g.:

```py
>>> d['role-templates'].get('readonly')
['step1;', 'step2;']
```

Comment: The get() call was the key. Thank you.